# How to create an application wide semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I have a spring boot web application. I have two places that cannot run at the same time. I have two methods: one is called by spring boot scheduler service and the other is called by a thread. I want to guarantee this two methods are not called at the same time.

I looked at java semaphores but I don't think they are global. If I could create a semaphore that is a singleton or a global semaphore would be great. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Can't you just create a `Semaphore` in a java config, give it a bean name `@Bean(name="semaphoreName")` and use this bean name when injecting the semaphor `@Autowire(name="semaphoreName")`?

Comment: Or a ReentrantLock might fit better in this case.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

Comment: @RenéLink thanks that worked.

Comment: @Redlab I'll look at the ReentrantLock looks a little complicated at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward solution is as follows: place these 2 methods (or intermediate methods which call the original methods) in the same class, declare these methods synchronized, and declare a singleton bean of that class.